# Creating Gallery for app with subFolders too?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gallery

I want to add gallery fragment or Activity to my app so i can show the downloaded files such as images and videos.

I am currently using this code for the purpose :

**Gallery Class** :

```
class GalleryClass extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {
    public static ArrayList < String > f = new ArrayList < > ();

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Gallery.gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Gallery.context));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        File dir = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("myFolder")));
        File[] FileList = dir.listFiles();
        if (FileList != null) {
            for (File aFileList: FileList) {
                f.add(aFileList.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        f.clear();
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        ImageAdapter(Context context1) {
            mContext = context1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return f.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(230, 230));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            Glide.with(Gallery.context).load("file://" + f.get(position))
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
                )
                .into(imageView);
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

**Gallery Fragment** :

```
    public Gallery() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gv);
        context = getActivity();
        GalleryClass process = new GalleryClass();
        process.execute();
        return view;
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine and it's loading images from the "MyFolder" but the MyFolder contains subfolders too and it is showing the errorplaceholder not the subfolder containing the images, and i want to show that subfolders too in the same view and when i click on that subfolder it will show the images which the folder contains.

How can i achieve same ?

Answer (score 0):

This will enlist all folder and subfolder containing png, jpg ,mp4 files.

```
    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("myFolder").toString();
    File file = new File(root_sd);
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        File  mFile = new File(file, list[i].getName());
        File dirList[] = mFile.listFiles();
        if(dirList == null) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < dirList.length; j++) {
            if(dirList[j].getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).endsWith(".png")||dirList[j].getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).endsWith(".jpg")||dirList[j].getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).endsWith(".mp4")){
                f.add(list[i].getName());
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does this code does ? Code only answers are not so useful .

Comment: @ADM it will scan all the folders but i need to scan specific folder and on that folder click it should show the images but it didn't seems to be in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
File f = new File(path);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File inFile : files) {
    if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // is directory
    }
}
```

Comment: then how to set the click listner for the folder click to show the images ?

Comment: Create two arraylist one for Image files and other for folder, so when adding the data in ArrayList apply the above logic                                                        if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // is directory
    } else{ // not directory                                                                                     
  } .... And while displaying apply the same, so you will be able to differentiate between the two and check if is directory then open the image files with that path otherwise show the files and folders